# Sqlite 3 on Windows, records not viewable to other users when stored as Administrator?

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

we use Sqlite 3 on windows to store our sync applications logs and state. Applications are written in c#, .net 4.5 and executed as windows services and/or console. We also use sqlite3.exe for debugging / log viewer.

Recently we found a odd thing, records generated by the windows services was not viewable from the sqlite3.exe tool, unless started as "Administrator". Services are running as "Local System".

I'v also tested to generate records by starting our console app as "Administrator". These records can then only be viewed in sqlite3.exe when started as "Administrator", otherwise they are "invisible". The same occurs when application is started as "normal" user (not as "Administrator" that is).

All application use the same database file, and during this testing file/folder security is set to "Everyone has full control".

Is this behavior by design, or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Windows redirects file accesses to administrator directories somewhere else; this is considered a feature. You should not put the DB into a directory not meant for data.

Comment: Sure, db should be put in a data directory, but that doesn't answers my question. How come sqlite3.exe displays different records depending on who executes it, when all records are in the same db-file? I guess this a sqlite question more than a general windows/file access question.

Comment: As I said, it is not the same file.

Comment: So even if sqlite3.exe reports that I'm using the same database file (with absolute full path), its not?

Comment: Windows changes the file path.